# How to determine link speed of interface in c?

Tags: c, macos, networking

On Linux, we can use ethtool `ioctl`s to get the link speed of an interface, but I don't see this function available on macOS. Additionally, in the case of Wi-Fi for example `ifconfig` may just show `autoselect` instead of the current PHY rate, and the output might not be particularly stable across different types of links.

Is there a way that we can, programmatically in C, and without spawning external programs / screen scraping, get interface link speeds?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The BSD source may be a starting point. Good luck.

```
$ wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-325/ifconfig.tproj/ifmedia.c
--2022-03-09 08:37:28--  https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-325/ifconfig.tproj/ifmedia.c
Resolving opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)... 17.253.21.202, 17.253.21.206
Connecting to opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)|17.253.21.202|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15325 (15K) [text/x-c]
Saving to: ‘ifmedia.c’

ifmedia.c                             100%[=======================================================================>]  14.97K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s   

2022-03-09 08:37:28 (344 KB/s) - ‘ifmedia.c’ saved [15325/15325]

$ wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.h
--2022-03-09 08:37:35--  https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.h
Resolving opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)... 17.253.21.205, 17.253.21.201
Connecting to opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)|17.253.21.205|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2166 (2.1K) [text/x-c]
Saving to: ‘ifconfig.h’

ifconfig.h                            100%[=======================================================================>]   2.12K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-03-09 08:37:36 (39.7 MB/s) - ‘ifconfig.h’ saved [2166/2166]

$ wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.c
--2022-03-09 08:37:47--  https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.c
Resolving opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)... 17.253.21.201, 17.253.21.205
Connecting to opensource.apple.com (opensource.apple.com)|17.253.21.201|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20378 (20K) [text/x-c]
Saving to: ‘ifconfig.c’

ifconfig.c                            100%[=======================================================================>]  19.90K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s   

2022-03-09 08:37:47 (480 KB/s) - ‘ifconfig.c’ saved [20378/20378]

$ gcc -DUSE_IF_MEDIA *.c
ifconfig.c:467:14: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                        clearaddr = NULL;
                                  ^ ~~~~
ifconfig.c:484:12: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                        newaddr = NULL;
                                ^ ~~~~
2 warnings generated.
ifmedia.c:151:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wextra-tokens]
#endif 0
       ^
       //
ifmedia.c:163:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wextra-tokens]
#endif 0
       ^
       //
2 warnings generated.
$ ./a.out en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,b6,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a8:60:b6:1f:8f:18 
    media: autoselect (none) status: inactive
    supported media: none autoselect 10baseT/UTP <half-duplex> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex,hw-loopback> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex,flow-control> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex,flow-control,hw-loopback> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex,energy-efficient-ethernet> 10baseT/UTP <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet> 100baseTX <half-duplex> 100baseTX <full-duplex> 100baseTX <full-duplex,hw-loopback> 100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control> 100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control,hw-loopback> 100baseTX <full-duplex,energy-efficient-ethernet> 100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet> 1000baseT <full-duplex> 1000baseT <full-duplex,hw-loopback> 1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control> 1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,hw-loopback> 1000baseT <full-duplex,energy-efficient-ethernet> 1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>
```

Comment: Just referring to some source files without pointing to specific functions or lines and without any further explanation is not likely to help answer the question.

Comment: The commands I provided will enable the OP to compile a fully working example that outputs the link statistics he wants, and highlights the relevant lines of code because the `-DUSE_IF_MEDIA` command line flag to the compiler will tell him which lines of code in the files downloaded are relevant. If he failed to figure that out he is probably not up to the task he has set himself.

Comment: Do you have nothing better to do with your life than be toxic to new users on Stack Overflow? ifmedia.h isn't even a suitable replacement for a single SIOCETHTOOL `ioctl()`.

Comment: As you're the OP, I'd very much like to apologize if my answer or comment came across as toxic. I really thought I was being helpful by providing a working example that had the output you wanted about link speeds, and I am not personally familiar enough with BSD system calls to construct a smaller tutorial.